# Getting NaN Value in fields with Jquery Code

Tags: jquery

I keep getting `NaN` Value in the the following fields:

- grossAmount
- netAmount
- retainedAmount

Here is my Jquery Code:

```
var $form = $('form.{/literal}{$form.formClass}{literal}');

$('input:text', $form).click( function() {
  var grossProc = $('#custom_274_-1', $form).val(0.3);
  var netproc = $('#custom_275_-1', $form).val(0.5);
  var loanSize = $('#custom_228_-1', $form).val(10000);
  var grossAmount = console.log(parseFloat($('#custom_241_-1', $form).val(loanSize*grossProc)));
  var netAmount = $('#custom_240_-1', $form).val(loanSize*netproc);
  var totalamountretained = grossAmount - netAmount;
  var retainedAmount = $('#custom_239_-1', $form).val(totalamountretained);
  var totalAmount = $('#total_amount', $form).val(netAmount);

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add some basic debugging or step-through to see what your actual values are:  `console.log(grossProc, netProc, loadSize)`

Comment: Hi Mate, i've got the debug in the console and when i look at Value it just shows Nan where can i see what its trying to parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val(value)` returns the jquery object(s) that it's applied to, for chaining, so:

```
var grossProc = $("#id").val(0.3);
```

is the same as

```
var grossProc = $("#id");
grossProc.val(0.3);
```

and you could do:

```
$("#id").val(0.3).hide();
```

You need to change this to:

```
var grossProc = $("#id").val(0.3).val();
```

Comment: Hi mate thanks for your reply! i updated the question as i saw i wasnt clearly about what fields where coming up as Nan

Comment: No, the variables `loanSize` and `grossProc` are jquery objects, not numbers because of how you are setting `grossProc = $("#id")`.  So it's going wrong before you see it going wrong - ie you're looking in the wrong place.  `parseFloat($("#id") * $("#id")` will clearly by NaN.  Just add `.val()` after every `.val(val)` call and you'll be ok.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted.  It's easy to look at where the error is occurring (parseFloat)

Answer (score 0):

I think your grossAmount value was `""` and when you try to `parseFloat(grossAmount)` it returns `NaN` and other variables using `grossAmount` also returns `NaN` while doing any opterations.

Comment: use parsefloat only if  `value !=="" && !isNaN(value)`

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning object to the variable, it should be like this

```
var grossAmount = parseFloat(loanSize*grossProc);

$('#custom_241_-1', $form).val(grossAmount);
```

Comment: As per my answer, `loanSize` and `grossProc` are also objects, not numbers.

Comment: you are using ``parseFloat`` on object

Comment: Same issue i think the issue is that .val(0.3) is not setting the value as a integer maybe...